# Behavior of array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a code as follows:

```
typedef struct Details {
    char a[32];
    char b[32];
    char c[32];
} Details_t;

char *xyz(Details_t *pdetails) {
    if ((NULL == pdetails->a) && (NULL == pdetails->b)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int len = 0;
    char *newString = NULL;
    len = strlen(a) + strlen(b);
    newString = (char *)calloc(1, len + 3);
    strcpy(newString, a);
    strcat(newString, ";");
    strcat(newString, b);
    strcat(newString, ";");

    return newString;
}
```

Now I am passing the address of this structure from `main()`.

```
main() {
    char *ret = NULL;
    Details_t var;
    memset((void *)&var, '\0', sizeof(Details_t));
    strcpy(var.b, "EXAMPLE");
    ret = xyz(&var);
    printf("OUTPUT==%s\n", ret);
}
```

My problem is: I am not copying any value in member a and I Have `memset()` structure details  with `NULL` so all the members which are not copied should be NULL. But in xyz function,the condition below gets failed.

```
if ((NULL == pdetails->a) && (NULL == pdetails->b))
```

and output which I get is below:

`OUTPUT==;EXAMPLE;`

Why this condition gets failed?

Comment: instead of `NULL==pdetails->a` use `strlen(pdetails->a)==0`

Comment: I hope `a,b and c` are to show the general case and not what's in you code. Also, `main()` should be, at least, some variation of `returnType main(){...}` if not `main(void)` generally `int main(void){...}` 'cause why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all the members which are not copied should be NULL

Thats not true, test this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Details{
    char a[32];
    char b[32];
    char c[32];
} Details_t;

int main(void)
{
    Details_t var, *pt;

    memset((void *)&var, '\0', sizeof(Details_t));
    printf("%s\n", var.a == NULL ? "null" : "not null"); /* output = not null */
    /* Also for a pointer */
    pt = &var;
    printf("%s\n", pt->a == NULL ? "null" : "not null"); /* output = not null */
    /* Maybe you want: */
    printf("%s\n", pt->a[0] == '\0' ? "empty" : "not empty"); /* output = empty */
    return 0;
}
```

Other minor problems:

`int main(void)` instead of `main()`

Don't cast `calloc`

`_t` suffix is reserved for POSIX

Answer (score 1):

when this `Details_t var;` is executed, var.a and var.b own address. So `var.a == NULL` will return false.

Comment: followup: the point is that the `Details_t::a` are ARRAYS not POINTERS. There's a real difference. Since the array is embedded inside the structure, it has an address almost always, and actually the IF condition is always true in your case. The `memset` will indeed make the whole memory zeroed out, but **there are no pointers** in the structure. After memset you will effectively have a structure with three arrays inside and the contents of those arrays will consist of 32 zeroed characters. You may exploit that! Hence, instead of `pdetails->a != NULL` just check `pdetails->a[0] == NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you able to compile with given Code, there should be

`len = strlen(pdetails->a) + strlen(pdetails->b);` rather than just accessing `a` and `b` which is not defined in function `xyz`.

Similar change needed in Line `strcpy(newString,a);` and `strcpy(newString,b);`

Now for your question comparing `NULL==pdetails->a` says checking address of a[0] is NULL or not which will never be TRUE.`pdetails` have got memory on stack so its elements too.

Comment: that was my writing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check out if this can help you :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct Details{
char a[32];
char b[32];
char c[32];
}Details_t;

char *xyz(Details_t *pdetails)
{
 if((strlen(pdetails->a)==0) && strlen(pdetails->a)==0)
 {
  return NULL;
 }
 int len = 0;
 char *newString = NULL;
  len = strlen(pdetails->a) + strlen(pdetails->a);
 newString  = (char *)calloc(1,len +3);
 strcpy(newString,pdetails->a);
 strcat(newString,";");
 strcat(newString,pdetails->a);
 strcat(newString,";");

 return newString;
}
//Now I am passing the address of this structure from main().

void main()
{
 char *ret = NULL;
 Details_t var;
 memset((void *)&var,'\0',sizeof(Details_t));
 strcpy(var.b,"EXAMPLE");
 ret = xyz(&var);
 printf("OUTPUT==%s\n",ret);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Why this condition gets failed ?

Because `a` and `b` are not pointers. They are arrays. You can not assign NULL to them. You can not assign anything to array at all.

This condition should work for you:

```
if( 0 == pdetails->a[0] + pdetails->b[0] )
```